# database query combining distinct and cast functions

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy declarative class with a datetime field in it, like:

```
class Logon(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(types.DateTime)
    event_type = Column(types.Integer)
```

I am interested in getting all dates for which there is at least an event, hence I use a distinct clause to play with:

```
session.query(sqlalchemy.func.distinct(Logon.timestamp))
```

Obviously that is boggus because timestamps are not unique within the same day. However it is strange that I get unicode strings instead of datetime instances:

```
 (u'2012-07-26 11:05:01.000000',), (u'2012-07-26 11:12:53.000000',), (u'2012-07-27 16:53:28.000000',)
```

What I really want is the distinct operator to use date and not datetime:

```
session.query(sqlalchemy.func.distinct(sqlalchemy.cast(Logon.timestamp,sqlalchemy.Date)))
```

The SQL looks also OK to me:

```
SELECT distinct(CAST(logons.timestamp AS DATE)) AS distinct_1 
FROM logons
```

However to my surprise the result of my query is a single entry with the year:

```
[(2012,)]
```

I could get my list of dates with an easy loop, but I am interested in learning how to combine the cast and distinct operators within SQL and/or SQLAlchemy

Comment: This doesn't look right. What database are you using? Might be good to post the engine URL.

Comment: @sayap which part doesn't look right to you? the first distinct without cast that retrieves tuples with unicode strings instead datetime or the second one with cast?

Comment: Oh, I mean the part where a string is returned instead of a datetime or a date. Both the code and the SQL look fine, and will definitely work with postgresql and mssql. Probably some quirk with sqlite, which I don't have much experience with.